# combine strings into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a web service to identify people and their functions from an external database that returns me a set of data if the login is successful. The data (that interests me right now) is separated in different strings as follow:

```
$groups="group1, group2, group3"
$functions="member, member, admin"
```

The first element of the string `$groups` corresponds to the first element of the `$functions` string.

We can have empty spots in the strings:

```
$groups="group1,, group3";
$functions="member,, admin";
```

What is the best way to combine them to obtain:

```
$usertype(
    group1=>member, 
    group2=>member, 
    group3=>admin,
);
```

Then I plan to use `array_search()` to get the name of the group that corresponds to a function.

Comment: Should the strings with empty spots still yield the same end result? Or is it just an example of what empty spots look like, i.e. the end result would only contain group1 and group3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)`($delimiter , $string)` and then filter the array? I think that would be a good way of doing it:

```
$groups="group1,, group3";
$functions="member,, admin";

$groups_array = array_map('trim',explode(',', $groups));
$functions_array = array_map('trim',explode(',', $functions));

$final = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($groups_array); $i++) {
    $final[$groups_array[$i]] = $functions_array[$i];
}

$merged = array_combine($groups_array, $functions_array);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/xY8nwDzr)

Comment: yes but then I get to separate arrays. The filter part, I do not understand.

Comment: thank you. I am checking it out. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: you are very welcome, and an upvote (if note answer accepted) would do for the time spent :)

Answer (score 5):

This is very trick especially when the first element is empty but here is a comprehensive solution

**What you need is :**

```
// Your Varriables
$groups = "group1,, group3";
$functions = "member,, admin";

// Break Into Array
$groups = explode(",", $groups);
$functions = explode(",", $functions);

// Combine both new Arrays and Output Result
$new = array_combine($groups, $functions);
print_r($new);
```

If you need to fix `null` values  then :

**Example :**

```
// Your Varriables
$groups = "group1,, group3";
$functions = "member,, admin";

// Break Into Array
$groups = explode(",", $groups);
$functions = explode(",", $functions);

// Fix Null Values
$groups = fixNull($groups, true);
$functions = fixNull($functions);

// Combine both new Arrays and Output Result
$new = array_combine($groups, $functions);
print_r($new);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [group1] => member
    [group2] => member
    [group3] => admin
)
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/private/cf1c0c9ecafe7a)

**More Complex:**

```
// Your Varriables
$groups = ",,, group3";
$functions = ",member,, admin";

// Fix Null Values
$groups = fixNull(explode(",", $groups), true);
$functions = fixNull(explode(",", $functions));

// Combine both new Arrays and Output Result
$new = array_combine($groups, $functions);
print_r($new);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [group4] => member
    [group5] => member
    [group6] => member
    [group3] => admin
)
```

[Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33341)

**Function Used**

```
function fixNull($array, $inc = false) {
    $ci = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE);
    if ($inc) {
        $next = array_filter($array);
        $next = current($next);
        $next ++;
    } else {
        $next = array_filter($array);
        sort($next);
        $next = end($next);
    }

    $next || $next = null;
    $modified = array();

    foreach($ci as $item) {
        $modified[] = empty($item) ? trim($next) : trim($item);
        if (! $ci->getInnerIterator()->current()) {
            $item || $item = $next;
            $next = $inc ? ++ $item : $item;
        }
    }
    return $modified;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$groups = explode(",", $groups);
$functions = explode(",", $functions);

//then use the elements of the $groups array as key and the elements of the $functions array as the value
$merged = array_combine($groups, $functions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should help:

```
$usertype = array_combine(explode(',', $groups), explode(',', $functions));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode()`](http://de3.php.net/explode) to make arrays of your strings, and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to use one array as keys, the other one as values.

```
$groups = "group1, group2, group3";
$functions = "member, member, admin";

$usertype = array_combine(explode(", ", $groups), explode(", ", $functions));
```

Answer (score 0):

explode and array_combine.
Note that you have a problem with whitespaces. Therefore use the following:

```
<?php
$groups="group1, group2, group3";
$functions="member, member, admin";

$groupArray = array_map(function($element){return trim($element);},      
explode(',',$groups)); // split into array and remove leading and ending whitespaces
$functionArray = array_map(function($element){return trim($element);},   
explode(',',$functions));  // split into array and remove leading and ending whitespaces

print_r(array_combine($groupArray,$functionArray));
?>
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [group1] => member
    [group2] => member
    [group3] => admin
)
```

EDIT: removed trim for the possibility that the first element is empty.

Comment: Why did you change the variables  ???? OP said `group1,, group3` not `group1, group2, group3`

Comment: That is OP's second example output, both options will work with my example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups="group1, group2, group3"
$functions="member, member, admin"

preg_match_all('/\w+/', $groups, $groups);
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $functions, $functions);

$final = array();
foreach ($groups[0] AS $key => $letter)
    $final[] = $letter . '=>' . $functions[0][$key];

echo join(', ', $final);
```